# Incrementing integers in particular positions in perl

Tags: regex, perl, increment

I have a string like this:

```
1,2,4 0:5 1:10 3:14
```

which I want to convert into

```
1,2,4 1:5 2:10 4:14
```

Only numbers before ":" have to be incremented by 1.

I have tried:

```
perl -w -e '$s="1,2,4 0:5 1:10 3:14"; 
$s =~ s/([0-9]*):/print(($1+1).":")/ge; 
print("$s\n");'
```

which strangely returns

```
1:2:4:1,2,4 15 110 114
```

Is there any easy way of achieving my objective?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You were close enough, but it has to match at least one digit, followed by `:`, and substitution part has to return desired result, not print it.

```
my $s = "1,2,4 0:5 1:10 3:14"; 
$s =~ s/([0-9]+) (?=:)/ $1+1 /xge; 
print $s, "\n";
```

Comment: It worked, thanks!
Can you explain what are the changes for: ?= and x (in xge) ?

Comment: Ok! I got it from http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions that it is a look-ahead assertion. Very neat! Thanks again!

Comment: @vervenumen `(?= )` is positive look ahead (doesn't go into `$1`), and `/x` ignores spaces/newlines when you want to write a regex which may be easier for reader/maintenance.